# how to get a single data of a room database

Tags: java, compiler-errors, android-room

I have multiple Acitivitys and in one of them I want to get a single column (poiLinks) of a single row (id -> Primary Key) of my room database. Pulling a whole row with another activity works, but with the new command i get a "null object reference" error and I cant figure out why. I want to pass an int to the function for the correct id-row. The Log says that the line in the Activity produces the error. I found similar questions here but i couldnt understand or implement the answers. Im new to Room so please be gentle :S.

(Entity -> DAO -> Repository -> ViewModel -> Activity)

My Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "route_table")
public class Route {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    int id = 0;

    @NonNull

    private String routeName;
    private double startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude;
    private String routeTime;
    private String poiLinks;

...

    public String getPoiLinks() {
        return this.poiLinks;
    }
}
```

My DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface RouteDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert(Route route);

...

    @Query("SELECT poiLinks FROM route_table WHERE id = :position")
    String getPoiLinks(int position);

}
```

My Repository:

```
public class RouteRepository {

    private RouteDao mRouteDao;
    private LiveData<List<Route>> mAllRoutes;

    RouteRepository(Application application){
        RouteRoomDatabase db = RouteRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mRouteDao = db.routeDao();
        mAllRoutes = mRouteDao.getRoutes();
    }

...

 String getPoiString(int position){
        String tempString = mRouteDao.getPoiLinks(position);
        return tempString;
    }

}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class RouteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private RouteRepository mRepository;
    private final LiveData<List<Route>> mAllRoutes;

    public RouteViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        mRepository = new RouteRepository(application);
        mAllRoutes = mRepository.getAllRouts();
    }

...

public String getPoiStrings(int position){
        String tempString = mRepository.getPoiString(position);
        return tempString;
    }

}
```

My Activity:

```
public class POIActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView iv_imageView1, iv_imageView2;
    int clickedPosition;
    String poiLinkString = "";

    RouteViewModel routeViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poiactivity);

        clickedPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("clickedPosition", 0);

        iv_imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_imageView1);
        iv_imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.iv_imageView2);

        poiLinkString = routeViewModel.getPoiStrings(clickedPosition); //This gives the Error

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `routeViewModel` is the one throwing the exception not the result. It is not initialized before calling .getPoiStrings(clickedPosition) inside `onCreate`

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        routeViewModel = new RouteViewModel(this.getApplication());

        ....
        poiLinkString = routeViewModel.getPoiStrings(clickedPosition); 

    }
```

This should fix it

Comment: thank you that fixed it a bit. but now it crashes beacuse it tries to use the main thread. I have this in my Database class:     private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);   But it only works for writing apparently?

Comment: if i try to return it as livedata i get an error in the activity. if this could solve the thread problem, how can i use the livedata in the activity?

Comment: You can't use main thread for accessing the Database. That is a different issue now. There are plenty of material online how to do it you even have it in the official docs for android. Give it a try and if you cant figure it put ask a new question

Comment: @VojinPurić actually you can by using `.allowMainThreadQueries`. Just that doing so can result in ANR's so for a published App it is not advised to use the main thread.

Comment: perfect thank you that worked! It makes sense that its not advised but for this little data i have it should be no problem.